# Nested resources - undefined method `comments_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

I'm working on a forum app which has 4 models: `Users`, `Boards`, `Topics` and `Comments`. My routes are:

```
resources :users do 
 resources :boards ### 'boards' contain 'topics'
 resources :topics ### 'topics' are similar to 'posts'
 resources :comments 
end

resources :topics do 
 resources :comments
end
```

I call a `link_to` method in my `posts#show` action with a `new_topic_comment_path` and pass the `@topic` variable as follows:

```
<%=link_to "Leave a reply", new_topic_comment_path(@topic) %>
```

and in my `comments#new` view, I have the following form:

```
<%=form_for @comment do |f| %>
<%=f.label :your_comment %>
<%=f.text_field :body %>
<%=f.submit "Post" %>
<%end%>
```

and here is my `comments#new` action:

```
def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
end
```

when `comments#new` is loaded from the `topics#show` view, I get an error saying `undefined method "comments_path"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! When using nested resources routing such as `foo/bar`, I need to pass two variables to the form in `comments#new` view. So instead of:

```
<%= form_for @bar do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

do

```
<%= form_for [@foo, @bar] do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
form_for [@topic, @comment] do |f|
```

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects)